# YAML to C# with Yaml.net for Unity

Tags: c#, yaml, yamldotnet

I currently am making a game where I have a file full of strings and different translations inside of a YAML file.

Here is an example of what it looks like.

```
en:
    player: 
        hello: hello
        thanks: thanks
    enemy: 
        hello: hello
es:
    player:
        hello: hola
        thanks: gracias
    enemy: 
        hello: hola
```

As you can see, I have 3 nested dictionaries.  The first shows the language - `en`, `es`, `cn`, or whatever national prefix.  Next, I have a list of dictionaries with character names.  These can be anything from `player` to `bob`.  Lastly, each character has a list of a dictionary of lines.

I am using YAML.net (a version for Unity - but using it seems no different than normal).

Here's an example of how my objects are laid out.

```
class Translation
{
    public Dictionary<string, Language> Language { get; set; }
}

class Language
{
    public Dictionary<string, Character> Character { get; set; }
}

class Character
{
    public Dictionary<string, Line> Line;
}

class Line
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

However, this doesn't work since the compiler complains that `en` and `es` are not properties of my `Translation` class.  How can I solve this problem without specifying every individual country code or character name?

Comment: `en` and `es` aren't properties, they're keys. Can you show the code where you get the error?

Comment: @Ic That would be when I deserialize - `return yml.Deserialize<Translation>(yaml_stuff);`  Apologies - `en` and `es` are not properties, but keys - which I think I correctly showed in defining `public Dictionary<string, Language> Language`